# Two hosts with same MAC address and different IP

Tags: ip, ping

3 Hosts: H1, H2 and H3 connected to switch. MAC(H1) = MAC(H2). They all have different IP.
What happens if H3 pings H1? And if H1 and H2 start pinging H3 at the same time?
(ARP table are cleared).

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess, I haven't tried this in practice.

At IP layer:

When Host3 tries to send packets it won't care about this, as ARP tables only map IP to MAC, not the other way around. It'll just remember both, just as if a single Host12 had both IPs assigned.

If Host1 receives a packet with its own MAC but Host2's IP, it might either discard it; or send an ICMP error; or act as a router and try to forward the packet to Host2. (It probably won't succeed though.) Overall, this depends on Host1's configuration and maybe its OS.

At MAC layer:

The switch has a similar cache – the MAC address to switchport lookup table. *This* will cause problems – once the switch learns that MAC½ is on port 1, it'll forward *all* packets to Host1... until the moment Host2 sends a packet of its own, and the switch updates its MAC table, and now everything goes to Host2 instead.

So both hosts will be able to send packets, but the receive path will​ bounce between the two every few moments.

Comment: That's a really good technical explanation.  In practical terms, I ran into this problem once when I cloned a VM in Virtualbox and forgot to reinitialize the MAC address.  I gave the clone a new IP address, but it wasn't able to communicate.  So the short answer to the question is: a breakdown in communication.

Comment: Thank you for the replies! I have done some tests in the lab with Wireshark. When H3 pings H1 some packets will go to H2. H2 will then forward the packets and send an ICMP Redirect (don't know why but Wireshark doesn't show those forwarded packets on H2's Wireshark, even though H1 receives all the ICMP packets).
I'm not sure about what happens when H1 and H2 ping H3. Everything looks ok (there are all the requests and replies) except for some ICMP requests that Wireshark marks as "No response found". Maybe because of the problems you were talking about (switch's cache).